# Joining tables in a nested serializer in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am kind of at my wits end here. Been searching for hours but i can't wrap my head around it. I have the following models:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    sentence = models.ForeignKey(Sentence)
    vocabulary = models.ForeignKey(Vocabulary)

class Sentence(models.Model):
    text= models.ForeignKey(Text)

class Text(models.Model):
    ...

class Vocabulary(models.Model):
   ...

class VocabularyStatus(models.Model):
   vocabulary = models.ForeignKey(Vocabulary)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   status1 = models.IntegerField(default=1)
   status2 = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

My desired output is in the form of:

```
text = {
    "sentences": {
         "words": {
                "id": 1
                "vocabulary": 1
                "status1": 1
                "status2": 1
         }
    }
}
```

So basically the hirarchy is Text > multiple sentences > multiple words. And the status is different based on the user who is doing the query.
The reason why Vocabulary is different from Word is because multiple words can have the same vocab (e.g uppercase/lowercase words)

Serializers:

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sentences = SentenceSerializer(many=True)

class SentenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    words = WordSerializer(many=True)

class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

With the queryset:

```
queryset = Text.objects.prefetch_related('sentences', 'sentences__words')
```

It works fine for that. But i have no idea how to link the data from VocabularyStatus into that. It is already a nested serializer. I tried:

```
queryset = Text.objects.prefetch_related('sentences', Prefetch('sentences__words', Word.objects.prefetch_related('vocabulary__vocabularystatus_set')))
```

But now i have no idea how to filter for the user with that or how to even display it in the serializer. It feels like this shouldn't be that hard as it is basically just a left join on vocabulary between the Word and VocabStat tables.

Appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The SerializerMethodField and it's get_FIELDNAME method allows for filtering on the related querysets.

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sentences = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_sentences(self, instance):
        sentence_queryset = Sentence.objects.filter(text=instance)
        serializer = SentenceSerializer(instance=sentence_queryset, many=True, read_only=True)

        return serializer.data


class SentenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    words = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_words(self, instance):
        word_queryset = Word.objects.filter(sentence=instance)
        serializer = WordSerializer(instance=word_queryset, many=True, read_only=True)

        return serializer.data
```